# Hyperref not working if a page is added to the PDF document

Tags: hyperref

I've recently started to use `hyperref` and it works fine in all files that I create fully myself. In many journals, however, a title page is automatically added to the manuscript -- and, in the resulting file, the hyperreferences don't work. They are still marked by little boxes of different colour, but, if you click them, nothing happens.

Any suggestions?

Here's what I typically include in the LaTeX file:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}                 % Inserts hyper-references in the PDF file
  \hypersetup{                        %
    pdfstartview=FitH,                % Fit the PDF file's width to window
    bookmarksopen=false,              % Open the bookmark tree
    bookmarksopenlevel=1              % Level to which bookmarks are open
              }                       %
```

Comment: You should mock up a minimal document pair showing how you create the functioning [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)-enabled document and add content that makes it non-functional. That would help current users replicate your setup, but also future visitors to this question.

Comment: i had such behavours as it was loaded in the end of other packages. If you have more packages you load try to load it earlyer.

Comment: @novski: `hyperref` shouldn't be loaded earlier. Basically it should be the last package to be loaded, apart from some exceptions like `glossaries` and `cleveref`

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: I don't think this is a latex problem, but a problem of how someone else adds the additional title page.

Comment: @samcarter: That's a possible cause. I thought of another reason: The O.P. adds pages with `\includepdf`, i.e. without preserving the hyperlink information

Comment: @ChristianHupfer From the deleted non-answer: "as the problem occurs when someone else adds pages to an already created PDF files". This makes me think that whatever tools are used in this process, there is not much tex can do in this.

Comment: @samcarter: Yes, sounds like a merging of pdffiles

Comment: Are you uploading a PDF to the journal? Then they add the title page? Then there is nothing you can do. Be thankful it accepts your PDF at all - until quite recently, uploading TeX-created PDFs failed.